# How to use form-control with mat-radio-group?

Tags: angular, angular-material

EDIT: [stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3g8bxf](http://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3g8bxf)

I'm having some difficulty getting my form to work properly. It seems that the form control rows are mousing over in between the radio button rows. Please can you help me to fix this problem. My code is as follows:

```
<form [formGroup]="formGroup" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
  <h3 class="identifyQuestion">Question #{{ question.questionId }} of {{ numberOfQuestions }}</h3>
  <div class="question">{{ question.question }}</div>
  <div *ngFor="let option of question.options; let i = index">
    <div class="form-group">
      <ul class="answers-list">
        <li class="form-control answer"
          [style.backgroundColor]="selectedRadioButtonOption === question.correctAnswer
                                  && selectedRadioButtonOption === option.optionValue ? '#43e756': '#f5f5f5'">
           <mat-radio-group name="answer" formControlName="answer" (change)="radioChange($event.value)">
              <div class="answerChoice">
                 <mat-radio-button [disableRipple]="true" [value]="option.optionValue"></mat-radio-button>
                 <label class="answerLabel">{{ option.optionText }}</label>
              </div>
         </mat-radio-group>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
 </div>
</form>
```

Comment: I tried moving the formControlName="answer" class="form-control" to the div with class answerChoice but now I don't see the label text.

Comment: could you please make a stackblitz problem so that we can get clear view of your problem

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3g8bxf

Comment: I don't understand what's for containers/question and components/question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what you want exactly, but what I understood, you want to highlight the correct answer. Please check the code in the stackblitz and let me know if it fulfils your purpose.

What I have done:

```
[style.backgroundColor]="formGroup.get('answer').value === question.correctAnswer && formGroup.get('answer').value === option.optionValue ? '#43e756': '#f5f5f5'">
```

Explanation: When the answer in the formcontrol matches with the correct answer, it will change the background color

Live Code: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-highlight-selected-radio)

Comment: No, I need it to work without the radio buttons (I added CSS to remove the radio buttons). Each box containing the answer should be clickable. The way it is now if you mouseover the top or bottom of an answer box that part is clickable, but the choice itself isn't.

Comment: The entire rectangle should be clickable. Also I need it to highlight with red background color for the incorrect answer (preferably with an x next to it) and green bg color for the correct answer (with a green checkmark next to it).

Comment: okay, I think, I did it what you want. please check the updated link https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-highlight-selected-radio. please let me know if it is helpful

Comment: Okay, this looks close to what I want. What I really wanted is that the row should highlight red or green also. Thanks for your help!

Comment: you can do it easily, if you can't, I might help if you say.

Comment: I will work on that next and will let you know if I have any further questions. Thanks again.

Comment: Hi, I made a small change to the code to move the checkmark or x inside the answer box and added some CSS. i added an ngClass to change the color of the boxes but it's showing up as red and I want the boxes to be initially gray. Please could you take a look at my Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3g8bxf. Please let me know if my changes came up as I have had difficulty saving the code. Thank you.

Comment: I tried changing the answer css to background-color: #f5f5f5 !important; but then the color of the box doesn't change. maybe i need to add another class to the ngClass for the initial state of the answers. and really i think all the logic should go into the ts file if possible

Comment: I added an 'initial' class to the ngClass but now all 3 incorrect answers are showing up as red when one incorrect answer is selected. And when I finish with the first question it seems that answers are highlighted in the following questions.